# Eloquent JavaScript: Persistent Group

Tags: javascript, oop

In the book, Eloquent JavaScript, it asks to make a class PGroup which is similar to a class made in a previous exercise. It basically is like a simplified Set class that has add, delete, and has methods. The specific part I don't understand at all is at the end. It says:

> "The constructor shouldn't be part of the class's interface (though
>   you'll definitely want to use it internally). Instead, there is an
>   empty instance, PGroup.empty, that can be used as a starting value.
>   Why do you need only one Pgroup.empty value, rather than having a
>   function that creates a new, empty map every time?"

This is the given answer to the problem:

```
class PGroup {
  constructor(members) {
    this.members = members;
  }

  add(value) {
    if (this.has(value)) return this;
    return new PGroup(this.members.concat([value]));
  }

  delete(value) {
    if (!this.has(value)) return this;
    return new PGroup(this.members.filter(m => m !== value));
  }

  has(value) {
    return this.members.includes(value);
  }
}

PGroup.empty = new PGroup([]);

let a = PGroup.empty.add("a");
let ab = a.add("b");
let b = ab.delete("a");
```

tldr: What is PGroup.empty?

edit: To clear up confusion, what I meant is that I don't understand the purpose of PGroup.empty or what it even is in relation to the class PGroup. Like, for example, is it a property of the constructor?

Comment: "What is PGroup.empty?" – an empty `PGroup`. Not sure what else you are looking for, TBH.

Comment: `PGroup.empty` is a static property that gets initialized to a new instance of `PGroup`. The choice of naming it `empty` is to emphasize that the particular instance of `PGgroup` will have its members initialized to an empty array.

Answer (score 4):

PGroup.empty represents an empty set. You can use PGroup.empty as the starting point to create more sets.

What makes this particular implementation of PGroup interesting is that the `add` and `delete` methods do not modify the existing PGroup instance that you're operating on. Instead, `add` and `delete` return entirely new PGroup instances. This means that every time you add or remove an element from a PGroup that you already have, you create an entirely new PGroup instance rather than modify your existing PGroup instance.

Using this pattern means that given an empty set (in our case PGroup.empty), we can create a whole bunch of other PGroups without ever explicitly using the `new` keyword. In particular, if we wanted a set of `['a', 'b', 'c']`, we could do the following:

```js
let abc = PGroup.empty.add('a').add('b').add('c');
```

Moreover, because the `PGroup.empty` instance itself does not change when you call the `add` method on it, you can use reuse the same `PGroup.empty` instance however many times you want.

```js
let xyz = PGroup.empty.add('x').add('y').add('z');
let efg = PGroup.empty.add('e').add('f').add('g');
```

This aspect of immutability allows us to satisfy the following requirement:

> The constructor shouldn't be part of the class's interface

Instead, we can use `add` and `delete` to create more instances of PGroup.

The technical term of having `add` and `delete` create a new instance of a PGroup rather than modify the existing instance of a PGroup is known as [immutibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

Comment: I have a question about the same exercise. I actually understand the PGroup.empty property. What I don't understand though is how this answer meets the criteria that the constructor should not be part of the classes' interface, since in the answer the constructor is clearly accessible and the book makes no mention of private constructors or how to implement them, which I believe is not a straightforward task.

Comment: It meets the criteria in the sense that it is not necessary to call the constructor in order to use a `PGroup` object. You are right that technically you still are able to call the constructor, but the addition of the `empty` static method means that it is no longer necessary.